# Change the default pyspark context

Tags: pyspark, cassandra-2.0

I am running Cassandra on 10.0.0.60 on the default port. When I launch `pyspark` I get a default context `sc`. However, that is pointing at Cassandra at I believe 127.0.0.1.

How do I change that so that it points at 10.0.0.60?

```
[idf@node1 python]$ pyspark
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
16/05/18 10:40:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015 18:08:32)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.

In [1]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass required configuration when executing `pyspark`:

```
pyspark --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.0.60
```

or add this to `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.